# When to set "done" to true in an iterator in javascript (off by one errors)

Tags: javascript, iterator

I've seen a few iterators implemented in javascript, and every time it seems like they're off by one (there's obviously something I'm missing) Here's an example

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

numbers[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  let idx = 0;
  return {
    next: function() {
      return {
        value: numbers[idx++],
        done: idx > numbers.length,
      };
    },
  };
};

// Run the custom iterator:
for (const num of numbers) console.log(num);
```

In this example, `done` is set to true when `idx > numbers.length`. However doesn't this mean that `numbers[3]` will not be set as `done = true` (even though there's no value for `numbers[3]`? I don't fully understand why this code works.

Would appreciate any help — thanks!

Comment: did you want  `idx >= numbers.length,`

Comment: Did you try running it? It works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to realise:

1. `done` does not indicate whether the returned value is the last one, but whether the iterator has no more value to return. As [Mozilla contributors write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols):

   > `done`
   >
   > A boolean that's false if the iterator was able to produce the next value in the sequence.
2. `idx++` evaluates and then increments, and so the expression for the `done` property works with an `idx` value that is one more than was used for setting the `value` property.

So we have these objects returned:

```
{ value: 1, done: false }
{ value: 2, done: false }
{ value: 3, done: false }
{ value: undefined, done: true }
```

### Alternative code without `++` side-effect

To eliminate the side effect of `++` mentioned in point 2, it maybe helps to look at this version, which produces the exact same `{value,done}` objects:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

numbers[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  let idx = -1; // <--- one less, so we can first increment
  return {
    next: function() {
      idx++; // First increment
      return {
        value: numbers[idx], // then use
        done: idx >= numbers.length, // ...as expected
      };
    },
  };
};

// Run the custom iterator:
for (const num of numbers) console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first time you call the iterator it sets `value` to `numbers[0]`, increments `idx` to `1`, then sets `done` to `1 > numbers.length`. So it returns `{value: 1, done: false}`

The second time, it sets `value` to `numbers[1]`, increments `idx` to `2`, and sets `done` to `2 > numbers.length`. So it returns `{value: 2, done: false}`.

The third time, it sets `value` to `numbers[2]`, increments `idx` to `3`, and sets `done` to `3 > numbers.length`. So it returns `{value: 3, done: false}`.

The fourth time, it sets `value` to `numbers[3]`, increments `idx` to `4`, and sets `done` to `4 > numbers.length`. So this time it returns `{value: undefined, done: true}`. This indicates that the iteration is complete.

The important thing is that the iterator doesn't set `done: true` on the last element, it does this when you've called it the next time *after* having reached the end. This design is necessary because some iterators may not be able to tell when they're returning the last element -- they need to try to get the next element and detect failure.